# Why is the sequence of statements in this while loop changing the output

Tags: python-3.x

Here is the code:

```
i = 1
while i < 6:
  print(i)
  i += 1
```

The output of this code is:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

While if I change the sequence of the statements:

```
i = 0
while i < 6:
  i += 1
  print(i)
```

Now the output is different

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

In the first one, 0 was included, but not 6, and in the second 0 was excluded, but 6 included. What is the reason?

Comment: the first code block: `i` starts at `1` - it will never ever print 0 ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python, as in most languages, execution moves down through a program line by line. In this case, the `while` loop causes the execution to loop from the end of the loop back up to the top while `i < 6`, but the execution still goes from top to bottom within the loop.

In the first case, then, the `while` loop does:

```
while i < 6:
    increment the value of i
    print out the current value of i
```

The first iteration of this loop starts with `i=0`, but `i` is incremented **before** it is printed, so the first value printed is `1`.

The last iteration of this loop starts with `i=5` (because if `i=6` the loop does not run), but as above `i` is incremented before it is printed, so the last value printed is `6`.

The second case, the `while` loop does:

```
while i < 6:
    print out the current value of i
    increment the value of i
```

So on the first iteration, `i` starts off as `0`, and it is printed (`0` is printed), then `i` is incremented to `1`.

On the last iteration, `i=5` (for the same reason as above - if at the beginning of the iteration `i=6` the iteration would not run). `i` is printed (`5` is printed) then `i` is incremented. `i` is now 6 so the loop will not run again.

---

The bottom line is that in `while` loops, the condition for the loop to run is checked exactly once per iteration: immediately before the iteration runs (or doesn't). Therefore, if the condition is true, the whole iteration will proceed regardless of what happens to the values checked by the condition in the meantime. The values will only be checked again once the current iteration is finished (we reach the bottom of the loop, and loop back up to the top).

This is not true for **all** loops; the [`do-while` loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do_while_loop), for example, checks its condition **after** the iteration has run, so a `do-while` loop will always run at least once.

Comment: I could not understand your comment  "the execution to loop from the end of the loop back up to the top" while i < 6, but the execution still goes from "top to bottom" within the loop. However, thanks for the elaboration. overall i got the idea.

Comment: Sorry - I suppose I used "loop" to mean two different things. What I meant is the loop works by 1. checking the condition (`i<6`), 2. if it's true, executing all the lines under the loop moving from top to bottom (in your case, print / increment) 3. "looping" back up to the top of the loop - starting back at step 1.

Answer (score 0):

In the second one 0 is excluded because you are incrementing the value of i before printing it. 
Similarly 6 is included in case2 because when i=5, inside the loop it is incremented to 6 before printing the value of i